# Is there an analytical solution to this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a trigonometric integral 
$$\int_0^x(1-a\sin^2x')^n\sin(x'-x)\sin x'\,\mathrm{d}x'~,$$
where $0 =< a <=1$, and $n=0, 1, 2,..$. Is there an analytical solution to this integral?

Comment: If $n$ was limited to small values, the results would not be very pleasant but can be written explicitely. If you want the results for any $n$, @Von Neumann showed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look. First, binomial expansion:

$$(1 - a\sin^2(x'))^n = \sum_{k =0}^n (-a \sin^2 x')^k$$

Second, let's expand the sine of the difference

$$\sin(x-x') = \sin x \cos x' - \cos x \sin x' $$

All together, arranging:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-a^k) \int_0^x (\sin^2 x' )^{n+1}(\sin x \cos x'- \cos x \sin x')\ \text{d}x'$$

This can be split into two terms, as you can easily see. Their integral are rather simple (just some tricks of substitutions and by parts iterations). Also consider that $\sin x $ and $\cos x$ are taken outside since you are integrating in $\text{d}x'$

$$\sin x \int_0^x (\sin ^2 x')^{n+1}\cos x' \ \text{d}x' = \frac{\sin ^{2 n+4}(x)}{2 n+3}$$

This is true provided that either the imaginary part of $x$ is zero, or the real part of $x$ lies between $0$ and $\pi$.

The other is a mess, I had to invoke Mathematica:

$$-\cos x \int_0^x (\sin ^2 x')^{n+2} \ \text{d}x' = -\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \sec (\pi  n)\cos(x)}{2 \Gamma \left(-n-\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma (n+3)}-\cos^2 (x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-n-\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)$$

The same conditions as before are needed.

Thence, in the end, we got a solution by series:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n (-a^k)\left(\frac{\sin ^{2 n+4}(x)}{2 n+3}  -\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \sec (\pi  n)\cos(x)}{2 \Gamma \left(-n-\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma (n+3)}-\cos^2 (x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-n-\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)\right)$$

Where also here $_2F_1(\star)$ is the Hypergeometric Special Function.

Not an analytic solution but you can go on from here, taking the first terms of the sum or asking mathematica if the sum can be written in another way.

Comment: Isn't your solution analytic in the sense that for almost every real $x$ there is a neighborhood where a convergent power series converges to the solution?

Comment: I totally agree with your solution. I just wonder if we could not avoid ("hide" would be a better word) the summation introducing somewhere the  Appell hypergeometric function of two variables (computing the antiderivative only). $\to +1$

Comment: @irchans Probably there is a misinterpretation of the words: I meant that it's not analytic in the sense of "finding a true anti derivative". This is indeed no, since it's a solution by series. That integral does not admit a primitive in the usual way, to say. About the other interpretation, I then think it's analytic!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you so much! I have to say I thought fast about that solution and I did not stop into details, but maybe tonight I'll face it better!

Comment: I think you omitted the binomial coefficients in the binomial expansion.